# change default program for SSMS shortcut in RUN

Tags: sql-server, windows

in my local system SQL server 2008 and 2014 both are installed. but when i type **ssms** in RUN (window + r) it will open a SQL server 2008 Management Studio, i want to open SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Please guide me how can i change the setting for my problem Thanks in advance

Comment: Update PATH env var?

Comment: Hello Ivan can you please describe more on that. i am unable to understand your point

Comment: Have you had a look on your PATH environment variable value already?